# FileBrowser/FileSelector for WPF

Tags: wpf, selector, explorer, file-browser

Does anybody know if there is a WindowsExplorer-like filebrowser which I can include in my WPF-window? I don't want use OpenFileDialog.

I have searched a bit and only found simple directory-trees or lists. I want to have an interface like it is in OpenFileDialog.

I'd be grateful for any assistance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's WinForms, but I've sucessfully used it in WPF applications:

http://gong-shell.sourceforge.net/

(LGPL Licenced)

Answer (score 5):

Use `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog`. Add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`, then run the following code:

```
        string selectedFolder = string.Empty;
        FolderBrowserDialog selectFolderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        selectFolderDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        if (selectFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            selectedFolder = selectFolderDialog.SelectedPath;
        }
```

This will work in Windows XP and Vista and you won't need to add any third-party references.

Answer (score 3):

I think the new 'CommonOpenFileDialog' is what you want. "***Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.CommonOpenFileDialog***" It is part of the win7 code pack, and will be part of .NET4.0 later.
Search for CommonOpenFileDialog you can find lot of resources on web.

http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/developers/archive/2009/04/16/light-up-with-windows-7-libraries.aspx

The code pack can be downloaded here http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Comment: the problem i have is, that i need to run my wpf application under windows xp. if i have understood right this solution only runs under windows vista and windows 7

Answer (score -1):

I am actually quite new to posting on this site but as Ryan Shripat pointed out; System.Windows.Forms should work.

For files you can use the System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog object.

Comment: [quote] I don't want use OpenFileDialog. [/quote] Oops, guess i should have read the question better.